# What is the SEO effect of AJAX loading translated content from a global cookieless domain to several international TLDs?

Tags: seo, domains, ajax, internationalization, translation

We have one .com that has all our unique content and then 25 other ccltd sites that are translated versions of the .com for each country we operate in.

We now want to serve up all static content of our global website (26 local country sites, .com, .co.uk, .se, etc) from one cookie-less subdomain. Benefit is speed improvement.

The question is whether from an SEO perspective, can all static content come from static.domain.com or should we do one for each ccltd where it should come form static.domain.xx (where xx is localised to the domain in question)

Comment: Are you talking about including the content with AJAX where the content resides in a central place but it is loaded from a variety of domains?

Comment: yes exactly. can we have one central place xxx.domain.com or should we have for each domain xxx.domain.de, xxx.domain.es

Comment: any help on this?